# SignalR - connection.hubName is undefined

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, ssl, https, signalr

I have the following SignalR hub class (only the top is shown):

```
[HubName("DataServiceHub")]
public class DataServiceHub : Hub, IDataServiceHub, IDisconnect, IConnected
{
.
.
```

I'm then self hosting the hub in a Console App using the following code in Main function:

```
string hubsUrl = appSettingsReader.GetValue("hubsUrl", typeof(string)).ToString();
var hubsServer = new Server(hubsUrl);
hubsServer.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.Zero;
hubsServer.MapHubs();
hubsServer.Start();
```

The values of hubsUrl is "http://localhost:4322/"

Once I've run up the Console App If I browse in Chrome "http://localhost:4322/signalr/hubs" I can see the SignalR javascript and my hub at the bottom:

```
signalR.dataServiceHub = {
    _: {
        hubName: 'dataServiceHub',
```

I'm trying to connect to this hub from an MVC3 app running on a HTTPS/SSL setup (i.e. the site url prefix is "https://localhost/"

In my Razor page I definately include the SignalR js:

```
<script src="/Website/Scripts/kendo/2012.2.710/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Website/Scripts/jquery.signalR-0.5.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:4322/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Note that we're using Kendo so the jquery js include is via that.

Then in the $(document).ready(function () {  I have the following:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
var connection = $.hubConnection('http://localhost:4322');
var hub = connection.dataServiceHub;
```

But 'hub' is always 'undefined'.

What am I missing here?

If this is cross domain problem - how do I resolve it?

Comment: My understanding is that the HubName parameter should start with lower case, to match the client name: "dataServiceHub", not "DataServiceHub".  (But then I'm having a problem similar to the above, so I'm certainly no authority.)

Comment: [This page](http://rionscode.wordpress.com/tag/an-exception-of-type-system-io-fileloadexception-occurred-in-microsoft-aspnet-signalr-core-dll-but-was-not-handled-in-user-code/) is relevant, since it can produce the "failed to export hub name" symptom by causing MapSignalR to fail, due to a mismatch in NuGet packages.  (This turned out to be my problem.)

Answer (score 5):

Hubs have 2 programming models and you're mixing them:

1. http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client
2. http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client

If you scroll to the bottom of those pages, there's an example that shows you what you need to do to use cross domain in each of the models.

Comment: Hi, I've actually updated the code since then and tried both.  So I now have:  $.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:4322/signalr' followed by  var hub = $.connection.dataServiceHub;  but still the hub is undefined

Comment: Another note: If I host the same hub class on another web project we have (which is on the same https://localhost/ domain) then the same javascript client code works (with the only change being the url set for the $.connection.hub.url).

Comment: You can just look at the generated script in the remote project and see if the hub got generated or not http://localhost:4322/signalr/hubs.

Comment: if you mean load up that url in a browser then yes the hub has been generated - I put the output from that part in the first post.

Comment: If you put all the pieces together you can figure out why it's undefined. When you include that script, it declares a global $.connection.hub on the page and $.connection.hub1..hubn, as properties. If you look at the generated script, you can clearly see the members that exists on the $.connection object and that should give you a clue as to what is going wrong.

Comment: Hi David - the problem seems to be with the MVC3 site being all on an HTTPS/SSL setup as I've now taken it all back onto normal HTTP and it works.  So, I guess the question is - is it possible to self host a SignalR hub on an HTTPS url (with SSL) as our MVC3 site definitely needs to be on HTTPS/SSL.

Comment: I have been experiencing the same problem with my ASP.NET web application. I am also using SSL. It works without SSL. Did you ever find a fix?

Comment: I don't see how ssl affects the generation of the javascript file. Is it different on SSL vs not? I basically described how it works and why you would get that error. Knowing that, what makes ssl different about the generated javascript.

Comment: @dfowler - I don't believe its SSL that's affecting the 'generation' of the javascript as my self-hosting console app isn't an SSL host yet.  It seems to be the 'usage' of the javascript - so calling the hub from the MVC3 site which is under SSL/HTTPS.  I won't be able to investigate again for a few days as I'm having to get something working for a training session next week - so for the moment that means without the HTTPS/SSL on the MVC3 site.  Will update when I can.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you are referencing jquery 1.6.4

Comment: Pranav, that's not really a complete enough answer.  Can you please try to improve it to be more helpful to the OP?

Comment: I'm referencing jquery 1.7.1 (via the inclusion of Kendo stuff).  This page has also worked against a different SignalR hub and no changes have been made to the javascript includes.

Comment: This is nothing to do with jQuery. See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Check in your `global.asax` file, if the line `routes.Clear();` is present there, please remove that line because it will clear signal routes.

Answer (score -1):

If you using https don't specify url neither through argument nor via 'url'-property in case when your hub working on the same url. Your hub, otherwise, will be undefined.

UPD

I screwed up guys. I was so hurry to post about specific behavior I 've just detected so I had no check out any possible version more.

However there was a bug in application that provides wrong url to hub with another port than was needed. therefore switching off property setting url for hub proxy has made my client workly.

watch for links your application provides...